# how efficient is iphone development with xmlvm

Tags: java, iphone, linux

I am going to make some practice of mobile development and I guess iphone development is the hottest area for this. Since I am using linux, I am not able to work with Apple iphone SDK. After making some research I found [xmlvm](http://www.xmlvm.org/overview/) which seems so cool for me. It enables us to develop with Java then convert it to native iphone application. I would like to ask that how efficient is developing an application using such xmlvm?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want answers you should accept some

Answer (score 2):

From reading the [XMLVM page about iPhone targeting](http://www.xmlvm.org/iphone/), it appears that this just takes Java code and generates the equivalent Objective-C code.  You will still need a Mac, Xcode, and the official iPhone SDK to compile and codesign an application for submission to the App Store or use on a non-jailbroken device.

Honestly, if you're going to be needing the full iPhone SDK anyway, you'll probably be best served by taking the time to learn Objective-C and the Cocoa frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you *must* compile with the Apple iPhone SDK compiler for an application to be acceptable to the App Store, hence you will need a Mac.

The MonoTouch IDE (not free) is the best bet for a Java programmer not wantning to go native.  It allows to develop in .NET (Mono) and target the iPhone.